# Mongoose - Implement a function for ALL schema's (not on each schema)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I've seen many examples where it is shown how to implement a custom transformation function on a schema (`toJSON()` for example, but could be another name).

But I don't want to keep duplicating that code for 'each' schema. Is there a way to implement it once globally, such that it will automatically be inherited by ALL schemas?

Here is an example of the `toJSON()` I would like to have.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

/**
 * toJSON implementation
 */
Schema.options.toJSON = {
  transform: function(doc, ret, options) {
    ret.id = ret._id;
    delete ret._id;
    delete ret.__v;
    return ret;
  }
};
```

I would like to add a few additional 'global' functions like the one above.

**Update 2018.02.13**: I define my models (schema's) in distinct modules (each their own `.js` file). So for example, I will have an `account/schema.js` module, an `profile/schema.js` module and so forth. I have at least 30+ schemas in my application.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: You might also be interested in [Mongoose Plugins](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/plugins.html).

--

You can define that function in a shared module, and import that module wherever you define your schemas. Then, you can achieve what you want by setting your schema's `toJSON` to this central, shared `toJSON` function.

```
/** sharedFunctions.js **/
function toJSON(...) { ... }
module.exports = { toJSON: toJSON }
```

--

```
/** userSchema.js **/
const sharedFunctions = require('path/to/sharedFunctions');
...
// In your schema definition:
  toJSON: sharedFunctions.toJSON
```

Comment: I've added an update to my question to indicate how I use/define my schemas. But I do like your idea. I could simply define all my functions in a `sharedFunctions.js` module and provide an initialization function which would accept the schema object and add each function to each. The only line of code I would have from each schema module would look like; `var shared = require('SharedMongooseFunctions");` and then call `shared.init(mySchema);`.

Comment: Mongoose Plugins might be the better approach. If you want to define some functionality for truly ALL schemas, you can easily do `mongoose.plugin(require('/path/to/plugin'))`.

Comment: Last time I looked at Mongoose Plugins, I didn't see a fit for what I needed. But I'll definitely take another detailed look. It may be a good fit after all.